# What did the end of the western front look like at the Swiss Border?

Tags: world-war-one, warfare, switzerland

After the German advance was stopped at the [First Battle of the Marne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Battle_of_the_Marne) in September 1914, the race to the sea (and also to the swiss border) began with both sides trying to take as much ground as they could.

So what did the end of the Western Front look like next to the Swiss border? I have found details and [images](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/28/WW1_Western_Front_at_Nieuport.jpg) of the northern end of the line in Nieuwpoort Belgium but can't help wondering what it might have looked like with an armed neutral country (Switzerland) in the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found some information in a [German speaking forum](http://www.geschichtsforum.de/258930-post4.html):

> Das Gebiet der Schweiz stiess an zwei Punkten unmittelbar an die Fronten, an der Grenze des heutigen Juras bei Pruntrut an die deutsch-französische Front und ab 1915 beim Stilfserjoch im Südosten Graubündens an die italienisch-österreichische Front.

Rough Translation:

> There were two connections to the front. One at the border at Prupunt (German-French front) and from 1915 one at the Stilfserljoch (Italian-Austrian front).

Some pictures from fortifications are at [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grenzbefestigungen_der_Schweiz#Erster_Weltkrieg) (but not from the direct border).

There is also an article [where WW1-front lines in Alsace reached Switzerland](http://www.schweizer-festungen.ch/1914-18_ww1.htm) with an [overview of the Western Front; the Swiss-Alsatian area is marked](http://www.schweizer-festungen.ch/images/1914-1918/Westfront%20WW1.JPG).

There is also a website about the "[Sundgaufront](http://sundgaufront.j-ehret.com/)" with [maps of the front](http://sundgaufront.j-ehret.com/frontkarte_sundgaufront.htm) (German: 'Frontkarte').